# Visual Studio 2010 - Can't see solution name/root after adding first project to solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do I add more projects to a solution.

Before there was a layout as such if I recall:

Solution Name >
Project1>
project2>

Now after creating a blank solution and adding the first (c# class library) project all I am seeing in the solution explorer is this project and there's no solution name that I can right click over and add more projects. If going to file> add>new project and then selecting MVC3 Web application I get the prompt:
**Cannot add the item because the item to add it to is not a solution folder or the solution**

Update: Strange, it only seems to occur when trying to add the MVC3 Website project. Adding other project types works.

All done. Appears to be a bug! Have to add any project type (did a c# class library) again other than an MVC3 empty WebSite and then solution name appears in solution explorer and you can add the MVC3 Website after.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have you got "Always show solution" flag on?

[image]

Comment: I tired that, says: Cannot add the item because the item to add it to is not a solution folder or the solution.

Comment: Save your work. Find the solution file if there is any in the saved location. Try to open the solution.

Comment: I have done that, the *.sln file is there and thee solution is open. The visual studio main window reads MySolutionName - Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: No, I didn't have the always show flag on. Suppose that would also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

All done. Appears to be a bug! Have to add any project type (did a c# class library) again other than an MVC3 empty WebSite and than solution name appears in solution explorer and you can add the MVC3 Website after.